# Why is my php Insert statement only inserting 74 items into phpMyAdmin?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, insert-statement

I recently tried to insert over 100 items into a phpMyAdmin database table. However after 74 rows had been successfully inserted it stopped inserting the items into the database correctly, instead it only inserted either blank rows or half of the information I wanted.

I checked the code, echoing bits out, testing the queries in phpMyAdmin and checked for any special characters which could cause any problems however there were no errors.

I decided to insert the data as two separate sets i.e. inserted 74 rows, deleted what I didn't require and then reinserted the remaining 50 rows everything inserted correctly.

This is the third time it has happened and just wanted to know if it was a known fault with phpMyAdmin or if when inserting more than 74 rows I need to change the code.

The insert is wrapped within a foreach loop the insert looks like this

$insertorderreference = "INSERT INTO check_order_reference 
                                            VALUE ('','$order_id','$order_item_id','$s','$newsku','$size','$quantity','','$product_name','$product_id','$site_name','$first_order','$last_order','$supplier_name','$date');";
                                            echo $insertorderreference.'
'; 
                                            mysql_query($insertorderreference, $connection);

------------------------------------------UPDATED ----------------------------------
This is what happens when I run the insert (this is where the problem occurs)

INSERT INTO check_order_reference VALUES ('','87','172','80','447430-739','S','1','172','Foundation Tshirt','1692','GLAS','86','104','Nike','09/10/2013/13/18');

INSERT INTO check_order_reference VALUES ('','98','195','80','447431-010','L','','','Nike Longer Knit Shorts - Black','1660','GLAS','86','','Nike','09/10/2013/13/18');

INSERT INTO check_order_reference VALUES ('','','187','80','','','','179','','','','','','Nike','09/10/2013/13/18');

INSERT INTO check_order_reference VALUES ('','','178','','','','','','','','','','','Nike','09/10/2013/13/18');

Comment: Please provide some sort of code ti look at.

Comment: we are man. we don't have any magic. please provide code you have tried

Comment: Look at the logs in the database to see what is actually arriving there.

Comment: use mysql_error() to debug your query

Comment: It is in a foreach loop which gets the data via posts from the previous page. It then inserts using a normal inserts
$insertorderreference = "INSERT INTO check_order_reference 
           VALUE ('','$order_id','$order_item_id','$s','$newsku','$size','$quantity','','$product_name','$product_id','$site_name','$first_order','$last_order','$supplier_name','$date');";
           echo $insertorderreference.'<br><br>'; 
           mysql_query($insertorderreference, $connection);

Answer (score 0):

```
please try like below way
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','db') or die(mysqli_error());
//place your host,user,pass,db details

$name='mahendra';
// get here post or other values ex- $_POST['name']
$data='sdfsdfsdf';
// $_POST['data'] if script is running on submit button of form

for($i=1;$i<=100;$i++){

$q="insert into mydemo set id='',name='".$name."',data='".$data."'";
//place your table name instead of mydemo and change insert query

$q=mysqli_query($con,$q);
}
//please check the your data for duplication of primary key value etc because of that your //script not inserting all records
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but unfortunately we cannot use mysqli (i know its the better option) as it isnt practical within the system we have. The system was created a few years ago so everything is done using mysql and is very rigid. It would need a massive overhaul of the entire system to incorporate mysqli.

Comment: in the insert query you are using value it is values please check syntax

Comment: INSERT INTO table_name
VALUES ('value1', 'value2', 'value3');

Comment: It could be that - tbf I didn't spot that before as it works with anything less than 74 - ill have a try now

Comment: No still encountering the same problem

Comment: This is what happens when I run the statement - this has been shortened but it runs normally and then doesn't work

INSERT INTO check_order_reference VALUES ('','98','195','80','447431-010','L','','','Nike Longer Knit Shorts - Black','1660','GLAS','86','','Nike','09/10/2013/13/18');

INSERT INTO check_order_reference VALUES ('','','187','80','','','','179','','','','','','Nike','09/10/2013/13/18');

Comment: use print_r(); to print the data what is getting inserted or you are passing to insert query in foreach loop. var_dump($insertorderreference) to debug query; and check what is wrong at number 74 query.